# Pointer Initializing to 0x1, Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, pointers

I've searched around and haven't found the exact problem I'm having or a potential solution to it.

I have a program that uses pointers for a linked list and I've narrowed down the problem to my pointers when they get initialized.  Below is the relevant code:

```
// Include header files
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int counter = 0;

// Structure prototype
struct numberList {
    int value;

    struct numberList *leftPtr = NULL;
    struct numberList *rightPtr = NULL;
};

// Function prototypes
struct numberList *getNextNumber(); // Reads next number from input file
void addNumToList(numberList *, numberList *, numberList *, numberList *); // Takes next user import and adds it to the current linked list
void printPointerValues(numberList *, numberList *, numberList *, numberList *); // Used for debug purposes

// Main
int main() {
    // Define variables
    string filename;
    int number;
    struct numberList *firstPtr, *midPtr, *newPtr, *lastPtr;

    printPointerValues(newPtr, firstPtr, midPtr, lastPtr);

    return 0;
}



void printPointerValues(numberList *newPtr, numberList *firstPtr, numberList *midPtr, numberList *lastPtr) {
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "counter:\t" << counter++ << endl;
    cout << "\n";
//  cout << "first value:\t" << firstPtr->value << endl;
    cout << "first address:\t" << firstPtr << endl;
    cout << "first left:\t" << firstPtr->leftPtr << endl;
    cout << "first right:\t" << firstPtr->rightPtr << endl;
    cout << "\n";
//  cout << "mid value:\t" << midPtr->value << endl;
    cout << "mid address:\t" << midPtr << endl;
    cout << "mid left:\t" << midPtr->leftPtr << endl;
    cout << "mid right:\t" << midPtr->rightPtr << endl;
    cout << "\n";
//  cout << "last value:\t" << lastPtr->value << endl;
    cout << "last address:\t" << lastPtr << endl;
//  cout << "last left:\t" << lastPtr->leftPtr << endl;
//  cout << "last right:\t" << lastPtr->rightPtr << endl;
    cout << "\n";
//  cout << "new value:\t" << newPtr->value << endl;
    cout << "newPtr address:\t" << newPtr << endl;
    cout << "newPtr left:\t" << newPtr->leftPtr << endl;
    cout << "newPtr right:\t" << newPtr->rightPtr << endl;
    cout << "\n\n\n";
}
```

I've cut out the rest of the code for the program because I'm currently getting errors with printing out the values of `lastPtr->leftPtr` and `lastPtr->rightPtr`.

When I run the program as shown above I get:

```
counter:    0

first address:  0xbfed29bc
first left: 0xbfed2c41
first right:    0xbfed2c53

mid address:    0xbfed29b4
mid left:   0
mid right:  0xbfed2c36

last address:   0x1

newPtr address: 0x8049653
newPtr left:    0xc629ffff
newPtr right:   0x8502fec1
```

When I run the code with the `leftPtr->leftPrt` and related bits uncommented in the `printPointerValues` function I get:

```
counter:    0

first address:  0xbf8c3ecc
first left: 0xbf8c5c41
first right:    0xbf8c5c53

mid address:    0xbf8c3ec4
mid left:   0
mid right:  0xbf8c5c36

last address:   0x1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The whole point of the function was to debug what was going wrong.  Fortunately it narrowed it down to what is shown above.  The problem is that I don't know why some of the pointers are initializing properly and others aren't.  Any ideas?  Also, I don't know why `midPtr->leftPtr` initialized to `NULL` ( or `0`) and none of the others did...

Comment: you havent initalized anything, you are just getting junk

Comment: i dont see why so many down votes - its a valid question, its just boring cos the same Q comes in every day. But we cant says its a dup cos it gets expressed so many different way. I earned my karma for today by answering it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 struct numberList *firstPtr, *midPtr, *newPtr, *lastPtr;
```

declares a bunch of pointers but doesnt set them to point at anything. You are just getting junk memory

You need to assign them to point at global, heap or stack lists

like this

```
firstPtr = new numberList();
```

or

```
numberList l1;
firstPtr = &l1;
```

Comment: I don't always herp, but when I herp I derp.  This was exactly the problem.  Thanks for the fast response.  Hopefully next time my question won't be for such a basic oversight.